# how to recursively check a nested dictionary keys and return specific value

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

i have a function with nested dictionary and a specipic number(in the code that i wrote it equals 1)
i need to write a recursive function that goes over the dictionary and returns only the values mapped to the keys that equals the specipic chosen number
here is what i wrote

```
def nested_get(d, key):
res=[]
for i in d.keys():
    if i == key:
        res.append(d[i])
        return res
    if type(d[i]) is dict:
        another = nested_get(d[i], key)
        if another is not None:
            return res + another
return []
```

print(nested_get({1:{1:"c",2:"b"},2:"b"},1))

i need it to return ['c'] but instead it returns [{1:'c',2:'b'}]

Comment: swap if's. check that is dict before

Comment: and you don't return None - remove the last return [] or check for empty list

Comment: Indentation is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program never makes it to the `if type(d[i]) is dict:` because it returns in the first `if` statement in the first iteration of the `for` loop.

Check if the value stored inside the key is a `dict` first, and don't return until after the `if` statements. You don't need the `return []` at the end because `res` will be empty if nothing was appended to it.

```
def nested_get(d, key):
    res=[]
    for i in d.keys():
        if type(d[i]) is dict:
            res.extend(nested_get(d[i], key))
        else:
            if i == key:
                res.append(d[i])
    return res

print(nested_get({1:{1:"c",2:"b"},2:"b"},1))
print(nested_get( {1:{1:"a",2:"b"},2:{1:{1:"c",2:"b"},2:"b"}},1))
```

Comment: when i try it with a deeper nested dictionary like {1:{1:"a",2:"b"},2:{1:{1:"c",2:"b"},2:"b"}} and the key is 1 it returns only ['a'] while it should return ['a','c']

Comment: Ah, so it does. Should only return at the end of the for loop. Have edited the code accordingly.

Comment: By the way, in case you haven't come across it before, `extend` is a more consise alternative to the `if another is not None...res + another` pattern you had in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

More compact and elegant version:

```
def nested_get(d, key):
    res = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            res += nested_get(v, key)
        elif k == key:
            res.append(v)
    return res
```